# notifyItemInserted and notifyItemRangeInserted when you don't know position

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to insert an item in my RecyclerView.Adapter at position 0 and remove items at specific positions.

Code:

```
fun updateData(new: Array<Item>, updatedId: String) {
    if (new.size > old.size) { // One item inserted
        old = new
        notifyItemInserted(0)
        notifyItemRangeInserted(0, 1)
    } else { // One item removed
        if (wallpapers.isEmpty()) {
            old = new
            notifyItemRemoved(0)
        } else {
            val removePosition = old.indexOfFirst { it.id == updatedId }
            old = new
            notifyItemRemoved(removePosition)
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(removePosition, 1)
            }
        }
    }
```

Niether the remove nor the insert works. It crashes with error message:

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{ce03856 position=2 id=-1, oldPos=0, pLpos:0 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{f978dbc VFE...... ......I. 0,169-1050,890 #7f0900d5 app:id/list}, adapter:com.company.app.menu.view.adapters.WallpaperFavoriteListAdapter@c1ed145, layout:com.company.app.menu.view.fragments.StartPageFragment$setHorizontalLayoutManagerWithItemWidth$1@d40509a, context:com.company.app.menu.view.MainActivity@5b913d5
```

Comment: try removing notifyItemRangeInserted(0, 1) and   notifyItemRangeRemoved(removePosition, 1)

Comment: Then it doesn't scroll to the first position which is requires.

Comment: then try  inserting notifyItemRangeInserted(0, 1) and notifyItemRangeRemoved(removePosition, 1) and removing  notifyItemInserted(0) notifyItemRemoved(removePosition)

Comment: And BTW you can use RecyclerView.scrollToPosition() to scroll to that position

Comment: Your first answer works combined with scrollToPosition(0) for inserting. However, for removing an element which is currently not visible, I cannot get the whole list to scroll one step to the left.